# How to connect an MSSQL database engine to a local network

Tags: sql-server, tcpip, sql-server-localdb

I need to let my public IP connect to a database that is located within the same local network.

Ex: MY public IP is: 190.222.222.222 The local IP of that PC is: 1.1.1.4 And this server already has an MSSQL (Localhost) engine. This means that if I connect to the Public IP it automatically calls me the LOCALHOST database engine.

I need that at the time of connecting to the public IP this call / connect to the local server database engine 1.1.1.7

The connection between server 1.1.1.4 and 1.1.1.7 is working. The firewall ports are open

Comment: SQL Server localdb does not allow remote connections. Do connect remotely, you need a SQL Server Express instance at a minimum.

Comment: I have SQL Server 2017 installed but how do I route the connection to the local IP?

Comment: BTW 1.0.0.0/24 is a public IP address range.

Answer (score 1):

the proper way - you need run Configuration Manager and check if tcp/ip support enabled for all necessary interfaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This way I have the configuration of my SQL. But at the time of connecting to the IP Public is calling me the database of the ip 1.1.1.4 (Localhost)

[image]
[image]

Comment: I thought it some terminology problems, localhost it always - 127.0.0.1, but default port for SQL Server - 1433, so if you do not use port in your connection it could be collisions

Comment: I have configured a different port. Ex 1435.

I have done the connection test from the local network and it works correctly

But still connects to the local database